# UITabBar Reappears when UIWebView is Double Tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am using a `UITabBarController` and loading `UIWebViews` in different tabs. I am using `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to hide the tab bar . But when I double click on any `UIWebView` the `UITabBar` appears.

I am not using storyboards.

So my question is how to keep the `UITabBar` from `unhiding` when the user double clicks on the `UIWebView` ?

Comment: could you pls show the code of how u r handling the double click,and where u r hiding the tab bar ?

Comment: I am not handling the double click. Its happening by default. For hiding the tab bar I am just setting self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

Comment: Have you tried to capture all double tap gestures from `UIWebView` ?

Comment: @zcui93 Capturing by native iOS or through JS in UIWebView ?

Comment: Native ones, so that you can prevent the gestures sent to other views. JS simply does not help with App level.

Comment: @zcui93 I actually haven't written any code to handle the tap gesture. The unhiding is happening by default. I can detect a double tap using UITapGestureRecognizer but how will I disable the unhiding.

Comment: Maybe gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch will work for the purpose, but it's not a good idea to override this default tab bar behaviour, as you changed the overall UX feeling. Maybe try to consider use another navigation method.